# How to check if Parse key is empty? If so then change it to 0 rather then have nothing

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm trying to get it so if a key in my user (virtual money is empty) which it is by default, then it sets it to the string value 0.

I've tried this but it appears to not work for some reason?

```
PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
if ([currentUser[@"Money"]  isEqual: @""])
{
    currentUser[@"Money"] = @"0";

}
```

Comment: Whoops fixed it, changed if conditional around to if (currentUser[@"Money"] == nil)

Comment: Your code may have logical error, be specific you want to check that string is only empty OR string is nil or empty ?

Comment: Have you considered setting the virtual money to 0 on creation? I don't know your reasoning for doing it as you are now, but if default is empty and you are always setting it to 0, just set it to 0 before saving the user. This is beneficial because your user might not have a connection or it might not save to Parse for a variety of reasons. As you have it written above there is no error checking. If you set it at the same time as the user creation you can have your user save error checking do all the work.

Answer (score 2):

```
PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
if ([currentUser[@"Money"]  isEqual: [NSNull null]])
{
    currentUser[@"Money"] = @"0";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`PFObject` (the subclass of `PFUser`) purposely behaves like `NSDictionary` and as you can read in the Parse documentation of [`objectForKey:`](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/objectForKey%3a)

> **Return Value**
>   The value associated with the given key, or `nil` if no value is associated with key.

So if you want to check whether the `PFUser` has a value set for a key, you have to check for `nil`, for instance

```
if (currentUser[@"Money"] == nil) {
    currentUser[@"Money"] = @"0";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If currentUser[@"Money"] is a NSString try this:

```
PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
if ([currentUser[@"Money"]  isEqualToString:@""])
{
    currentUser[@"Money"] = @"0";

}
```

Also ou can check if `[string length] == 0`. This will check if it's a valid but empty string (@"") as well as if its nil, since calling length on nil will also return 0.

If it is an NSNumber try:

```
PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
if (currentUser[@"Money"]==nil)
{
    currentUser[@"Money"] = @"0";

}
```